# function to get the subtraction result state that is it positive or negative?

Tags: php, subtraction

I am performing subtraction on two variable.

```
$first_variable = 20;
$second_variable = 30;
$result = $first_variable - $second_variable;
```

So how do i get that the result `$result` is positive or negative? 
Have any `PHP` function to determine that the result of subtraction is positive or negative? 
I know the i can use `if` statement to get it done. but i am asking for any predefined function to do it.

The reason i asked it hear is just a curiosity.

Comment: `if($result >= 0){echo "positive";}else{echo "negative"; }`

Comment: what is the reason you want a function do the job instead a simple `if($c < 0)`..??

Comment: one is for simplicity and second is for curiosity

Comment: can i know why i get the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php **gmp_sign** function to achieve that check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-sign.php)

**Example**:-

```
<?php
// positive
echo gmp_sign("500") . "\n";

// negative
echo gmp_sign("-500") . "\n";

// zero
echo gmp_sign("0") . "\n";
?>
```

output

```
1
-1
0
```

Comment: @always-a-learner you are welcome ,if you doubt is cleared then you can close your question by accepting my answer :)

Comment: Done sir, can you please give up vote to the question?

Comment: yes i get that some one down voted too so i did not see that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for pure academic purposes, you can sort of do it with a function:

```
$sign = sprintf("%+d", $number)[0];
```

Comment: i have read the documentation it's interesting. thanks @Colburton